# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when try Compilation in Solidity

Tags: javascript, solidity

When I try to execute in console

```
node compile.js
```

I get this error.

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when try Compilation in Solidity

**Invox.sol:**

```
pragma solidity  ^0.4.25;

contract Invox {
    string public message;

    function Invox (string initialmessage) public {
        message = initialmessage;
    }
    function setMessage(string _message) public {
        message = _message;  
    }
}
```

**compile.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const invoxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'invox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(invoxPath, 'utf8');
//We have replaced the following line, but the issue persists
module.compile = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Invox'];
//console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "invox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "solc": "^0.4.25"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`? most likely it is a `solc` version issue.

Comment: Just do it!!  Thanks for answering

Comment: @IftifarTaz
I have installed version 6.10.2 of solc but still giving the same error I am blocked

Comment: With the code provided it compiles for me. and always use `solc` version same as `pragma solidity` in contract.

Comment: I got too excited. This did not work either. I still don't really know what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm install --save solc@0.4.17

run the above command and change the solidity version in your invox.sol

pragma solidity  ^0.4.25; -> pragma solidity  ^0.4.17;

Comment: Oh great it worked! ...
Now it's time to fix the error of installing `npm install --save web3@^1.0.0-beta.36`
There is no way to find a solution.

Comment: I have had errors in the installation in windows but it seems to work. forget the above then. A million thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your nodejs version is too **high**.

I met this problem when node `v12.16.0` is used. 
However, when I switched it to `v8.5.0`, everything works well.

Comment: Thanks for answare me. 
My version is  "solc": "^0.4.25"...
You can see that in JSON file.

Comment: We have replaced the following line, but the issue persists:
`module.compile = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Invox']`